Use C++/WinRT component (but really any WinRT component) in WPF .NET 6
I would like to write a WPF application, but build it on modern frameworks as much as possible, including for example .NET 6 or maybe even higher.
I have some C++ code that I want to call, and I like WinRT as a component model instead of low level P/Invoke.
I already have managed to integrate my C++ code into a WinUI3 app using CsWinRT. Now I try to do the same with my WPF app. My attempt can be seen at https://github.com/mmarczell-graphisoft/winrtbug
As long as I do not have the using directive in my WPF C# code, nor any code using those definitions, the C# projection file does get generated under obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\Generated Files\CsWinRT. However as soon as I enter the using directive and rebuild, this file is no longer there.
What am I doing wrong?

I have found some documentation about similar usecases, but they are some years old and do not seem not directly applicable.
Originally, it was not supported to use WinRT components in non packaged apps.
https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/256
Then in 2019 "Registration-free WinRT" was announced:
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/
with sample code:
https://github.com/microsoft/RegFree_WinRT
However with .NET 5, the ability to directly reference a .winmd was removed from .NET and extracted into the CsWinRT package:
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT
and that is what I'm failing to configure correctly. The documentation states that direct project references are not possible, and instead a two phase build process should be used, with the first phase packaging the library as a NuGet package, and the top level application referencing that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/net-projection-from-cppwinrt-component
However MS employees in GitHub discussions are repeatedly suggesting that this is in fact unnecessary, as CsWinRT supports a simpler workflow by directly referencing the projects, for example at
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/discussions/1072#discussioncomment-8497693 and https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/1289#issuecomment-1481878399
I have also submitted this question as a GitHub issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/1543

Have you done everything that's specified in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/net-projection-from-cppwinrt-component (that needs an intermediary nuget package, etc.)

@SimonMourier - I know that documentation, but it turned out to be misleading, because even in my example repo, with the WinUI project for example, it does work by directly referencing the C++/WinRT project, without the whole nuget dance. The whole journey how I got this far, and the advice I got from MS employees, can be seen here: https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/discussions/1072

What you know or don't know should be in the question. Why don't you want to use the documented way that works?

@SimonMourier For two reasons: 1. MS employees repeatedly suggesting not to use it (see my edits) 2. Developer experience. It is a nightmare to develop a C++ backend and a UI frontend in the same application if every change to the backend requires a new NuGet packaging, version code bump; and debugging also becomes much more cumbersome.

These articles are old. With .NET 8 I can make the offical sample (https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/tree/master/src/Samples/NetProjectionSample) work quite easily w/o a nuget and a console app (at same level than other projects). with CsWinRTIncludes. However same layout doesn't work with an WPF app (weird!) but it can work if you force CsWinRT command line. Check both csproj here https://pastebin.com/raw/mnmFb3Mf (PS UseWPF in console app was just for testing)

It is precisely that "weird!" that I'm interested in. But I will take a look at your pastebin

It's not exactly the same weirdness as your problem (and it works fine in a console app)

The workaround in your pastebin worked. Thanks! If you publish that as an answer here I will accept it.

Many articles pointed out here are old (aka few years, but few years are ages with .NET Core), and with recent Framework some things are easier than they were but it's hard to find the solution.
So, starting from this (official) tutorial Generate a C# projection from a C++/WinRT component, distribute as a NuGet for .NET apps wich is available as sample code here C#/WinRT Projection Sample. First thing to do is update all packages, especially CsWinRT which is completely outdated (current version as of today is 2.0.7).
And then, thanks to this newer CsWinRT, you don't even need the use an intermediary Nuget project like what's explained in the sample, because this new CsWinRT generates some .cs file on the fly for us from the component's .winmd file (metadata).
Just build the SimpleMathComponent C++/WinRT project, and now you can reference it in a console app with a .csproj like this, using .NET 8 and x64 (debug or release)
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT" Version="2.0.7" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SimpleMathComponent\SimpleMathComponent.vcxproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <CsWinRTIncludes>
        SimpleMathComponent;
    </CsWinRTIncludes>
</PropertyGroup>

We can see the .cs projection auto-generated file in the obj directory:

Now, with a WPF project, the same project layout doesn't work. For some reason, the SimpleMathComponent component is not picked up by CsWinRT  for code generation (the only real difference I can see is OutputType, Exe vs WinExe) and the SimpleMathComponent.cs is not generated which causes a compilation error. Looks like a bug to me.
A possible workaround is to feed CsWinRT directly with the input it needs, something like this;
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT" Version="2.0.7" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\SimpleMathComponent\SimpleMathComponent.vcxproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <CsWinRTParams>
            -target net6.0
            -input 10.0.19041.0
            -input "$(BuildOutDir)SimpleMathComponent\bin\SimpleMathComponent\SimpleMathComponent.winmd"
            -output "$(IntermediateOutputPath)\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\Generated Files\CsWinRT"
            -exclude Windows
            -exclude Microsoft
            -include SimpleMathComponent
        </CsWinRTParams>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Obviously it's less practical than the Console app version (and it needs to be adapted when varying .NET versions, SDK versions, etc.).
