Control, created with C++/WinRT Component, doesn't appear in C#/WinRT App
I want to use C++ as part of WinUI3.
I'm facing an issue where the C# component displays properly, but the C++ component doesn't.
Result
Therefore, I followed a Microsoft article to implement a C++/WinRT component and a C#/WinRT component, and then imported them into WinUI3.
C++/WinRT
C#/WinRT
My repository
[Visual Studio] 2022 Community
[Target] net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0
BgLabelControl.idl
namespace CppWinRTComponent
{
    runtimeclass BgLabelControl : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control
    {
        BgLabelControl();
        static Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty LabelProperty{ get; };
        String Label;
    }
}

BgLabelControl.h
#pragma once

#include "BgLabelControl.g.h"

namespace winrt::CppWinRTComponent::implementation
{
    struct BgLabelControl : BgLabelControlT<BgLabelControl>
    {
        BgLabelControl();

        winrt::hstring Label() const
        {
            return winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(GetValue(m_labelProperty));
        }

        void Label(winrt::hstring const& value) const
        {
            SetValue(m_labelProperty, winrt::box_value(value));
        }

        static Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty LabelProperty() { return m_labelProperty; }

        static void OnLabelChanged(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const&, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs const&);

    private:
        static Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty m_labelProperty;
    };
}

namespace winrt::CppWinRTComponent::factory_implementation
{
    struct BgLabelControl : BgLabelControlT<BgLabelControl, implementation::BgLabelControl>
    {
    };
}

BgLabelControll.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "BgLabelControl.h"
#if __has_include("BgLabelControl.g.cpp")
#include "BgLabelControl.g.cpp"
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace winrt::CppWinRTComponent::implementation
{
    Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty BgLabelControl::m_labelProperty =
        Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
            L"Label",
            winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::hstring>(),
            winrt::xaml_typename<CppWinRTComponent::BgLabelControl>(),
            Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{ winrt::box_value(L"default label"), Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyChangedCallback{ &BgLabelControl::OnLabelChanged } }
    );

    BgLabelControl::BgLabelControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey(winrt::box_value(L"CppWinRTComponent.BgLabelControl"));
    }

    void BgLabelControl::OnLabelChanged(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& d, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs const& /* e */)
    {
        if (CppWinRTComponent::BgLabelControl theControl{ d.try_as<CppWinRTComponent::BgLabelControl>() })
        {
            // Call members of the projected type via theControl.

            CppWinRTComponent::implementation::BgLabelControl* ptr{ winrt::get_self<CppWinRTComponent::implementation::BgLabelControl>(theControl) };
            // Call members of the implementation type via ptr.
        }
    }
}

Directory.Build.props
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildOutDir>$([MSBuild]::NormalizeDirectory('$(SolutionDir)', '_build', '$(Platform)', '$(Configuration)'))</BuildOutDir>
    <OutDir>$([MSBuild]::NormalizeDirectory('$(BuildOutDir)', '$(MSBuildProjectName)', 'bin'))</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$([MSBuild]::NormalizeDirectory('$(BuildOutDir)', '$(MSBuildProjectName)', 'obj'))</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

CppWinRTProjecton.nuspce
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>CppWinRTComponent</id>
    <version>0.1.0-prerelease</version>
    <authors>Contoso Math Inc.</authors>
    <description>A simple component with basic math operations</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\_build\AnyCPU\Release\CppWinRTProjection\bin\CppWinRTProjection.dll" target="lib\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\CppWinRTProjection.dll" />
    <file src="..\..\_build\x64\Release\CppWinRTComponent\bin\CppWinRTComponent.winmd" target="lib\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\CppWinRTComponent.winmd" />
    <file src="..\..\_build\x64\Release\CppWinRTComponent\bin\CppWinRTComponent.dll" target="runtimes\win10-x64\native\CppWinRTComponent.dll" />
  </files>
</package>

CppWinRTProjection.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230913002" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.755" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT" Version="2.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CppWinRTComponent\CppWinRTComponent.vcxproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="nuget\CppWinRTProjection.nuspec" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CsWinRTIncludes>CppWinRTComponent</CsWinRTIncludes>
    <CsWinRTGeneratedFilesDir>$(OutDir)</CsWinRTGeneratedFilesDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratedNugetDir>.\nuget\</GeneratedNugetDir>
    <NuspecFile>$(GeneratedNugetDir)CppWinRTProjection.nuspec</NuspecFile>
    <OutputPath>$(GeneratedNugetDir)</OutputPath>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

BgLabelControls
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Documents;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace CsWinRTComponent
{
    public sealed class BgLabelControl : Control
    {
        DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Label),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BgLabelControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLabelChanged)));

        public string Label
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
            set => SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
        }

        public BgLabelControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(BgLabelControl);
        }

        public bool HasLabelValue { get; set; }

        private static void OnLabelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BgLabelControl labelControl = d as BgLabelControl; //null checks omitted
            String s = e.NewValue as String; //null checks omitted
            if (s == String.Empty)
            {
                labelControl.HasLabelValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                labelControl.HasLabelValue = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

CsWinRTApp.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>CsWinRTApp</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreSources>
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;
      ../CppWinRTProjection/nuget
    </RestoreSources>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Remove="Themes\Generic.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230913002" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.755" />
    <PackageReference Include="CppWinRTComponent" Version="0.1.0-prerelease" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CsWinRTComponent\CsWinRTComponent.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Themes\Generic.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution 
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if 
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

MainWindow.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="CsWinRTApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CsWinRTApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cppcomponent="using:CppWinRTComponent"
    xmlns:cscomponent="using:CsWinRTComponent"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Activated="Window_Activated">

    <StackPanel Name="myStack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <!--<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>-->
        <cppcomponent:BgLabelControl Background="Blue" Label="C++"/>
        <cscomponent:BgLabelControl Background="Red" Label="C#"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

There are no errors or warnings, can you tell what's wrong.

Please show a [mcve].

@IInspectable
This is. https://github.com/0xopenfields/WinRTAppExample1

As the link explains, the [mcve] needs to be in the question. Links to external resources will inevitably become inaccessible over time.

@IInspectable This is minimal. It cannot be smaller since it runs on C++, C#, XAML, NuGet, and multiple projects.

@IInspectable Add codes. It's OK?

Usually, you shouldn't need nuget. Might want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78316887/use-c-winrt-component-but-really-any-winrt-component-in-wpf-net-6

Does the C# host application have a manifest? It needs to contain an ActivatableClass element so that the system knows where to find the control implementation.

Also, make sure to observe any XAML binding diagnostics.

@IInspectable - when using (recent) CsWinRT, you don't need to register the component, it can be "activated" without being registered when/if it generates the support C# code.

@SimonMourier The whole point of the manifest is to support registration-free COM. The manifest doesn't register coclasses. Instead, it lets the system know where to find the class factories. I don't know how much of that is handled by CsWinRT or MSBuild.

@IInspectable - there's no manifest involved here, and it's not regfree COM either, the generated (recent) CsWinRT .NET stubs will just call DllGetActivationFactory exported by the WinRT component https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/src/cswinrt/strings/WinRT.cs#L347

@SimonMourier Where does the fileName argument come from though? That information is commonly stored in the manifest, alongside the type name(s).

@IInspectable - The "projection" dll resides aside the "component" dll in this case (or in a runtime directory). You can have a look at this sample (needs and up-to-date cswinrt)

@Simon Mourier Thanks!! I'd prefer a method that doesn't involve treating it as a NuGet package, as I want to distribute it as a DLL.
Is it possible to convert a control into a DLL using C++?

@IInspectable
If a manifest is required, then CppWinRTComponent.Class shouldn't be importable either. Errors should also occur.
If possible, it would be best if it could be treated as a DLL like A's, rather than as a NuGet package. Classes that do not inherit controls, such as CppWinRTComponent.Class, can be referenced. However, when inheriting controls, as with CppWinRTComponent.BgLabelControl, no errors or warnings are displayed, but it doesn't show up either.

@ShimpeiHirakida - not sure what you mean by "convert a control into a DLL using C++".

@SimonMourier
Like, CppWinRTComponent::BgLabelControl, implement C++/WinRT "struct BgLabelControl : BgLabelControlT" to CppWinRTComponent.dll.
On CsWinRTApp, reference to CppWinRTComponent.dll. (Now, Nuget -> CsWinRTProjection -> CppWinRTComponent).

Thank, guys.
Succeeded, show C++/WinRT control.
Change 1. no use Nuget.
Change 2. correct CSWinRTApp.csproj. (direct referece to CppWinRTComponent.vcxproj)
update, my repos.
https://github.com/0xopenfields/WinRTAppExample1.git

@ShimpeiHirakida - you should now add a detailed answer to your question if you're happy

@SimonMourier
Sorry, I have been logged out, long ago.
I resloved this problem, thank your response.
